# How to Import multiple sheets (aka tabs) from Google Sheets?

Tags: import

One can Import multiple sheets from an Excel file, say sheet "`n`" with `Import["file.xls"][[n]]`,
but how to do that with a Google sheet? I only know how to import the first sheet.

Comment: How are you importing from Google Sheets right now?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.

Save the sheet to your google drive. Right-click, "Get Link" Make sure that **"Anyone with link"** setting is selected as opposed to "Restricted".

"Copy Link" to get the link. Paste it in a notebook cell and put quotes around it:

`https : //  docs . google . com/spreadsheets/d/ 1 kut8YLiPKMXFs_ 8 Zpt9quQUa0K7yq0pP4QEV_sM2umo/edit?usp = sharing`

Get rid of the `edit?usp=sharing` and instead write: `export?format=xlsx` as shown for the **fictitious** link here.

```
url = URL[
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kut8YLiPKMXFs_\
Zpt9quQUa0K7yq0pP4QEV_sM2umo/export?format=xlsx"]
data = Import[url]
```

In my example, there are two sheets with toy data:

> ```
> {{{"a", 1.}, {"b", 2.}, {"c", 3.}, {"d", 4.}, {"e", 5.}, {"f", 
>    6.}, {"g", 7.}, {"h", 8.}, {"i", 9.}, {"j", 10.}}, {{"one", 
>    1.}, {"two", 2.}, {"three", 3.}, {"four", 4.}, {"five", 
>    5.}, {"six", 6.}, {"seven", 7.}, {"eight", 8.}, {"nine", 
>    9.}, {"ten", 10.}}}
> ```

that you can get as `data[[1]]` and `data[[2]]`.

Comment: Thank you,  Syed,  this was exactly what I needed.  I had tried "/export?format=xls" but had neglected to try the xlsx extension.  (Otherwise I have been using "csv" for the single sheet documents.)  You've been very helpful.

Comment: I am glad, I was able to help you. Please consider accepting the answer as it motivates future visitors to the page to actually read anything on the page.